# Number line when creating empty windows store app (8.1)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

I am new to App development. One Thing I didn't figure out is:

When I create an Empty Windows App Project an start this Projekt in Visual Studio I get a Numberline in the App. (Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015)

[image]

What Does this Numbers mean and how can I disable it?

Comment: This should be some debug information. Try starting the app from outside visual studio to see if they are still there

Answer (score 1):

It's a framerate counter, displayed only when running the app with attached debugger.
If it bothers you go to *App.xaml.cs* file and comment the following lines:

```
#if DEBUG
      if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
      {
          this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
      }
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :-)